# Combining multiple maps with vectors into one map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stdmap

I have a question about combining maps that have vectors as the value section. for instance, I might have the following:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<Affector*> > affectors;
```

I want to build this map by combining multiple smaller maps. For instance:

```
for (auto ch = chList.begin(); ch != chList.end(); ++ch)
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<Affector*> > tempAff = ch->getemng()->getAffectorsInOrder();
    std::map<int, std::vector<Affector*> > tempAff2 = ch->getpmng()->getAffectorsInOrder()
    //I want to append both of these maps to the top level affectors map
}
```

I can think of the obvious solution which would be

```
for (auto ch = chList.begin(); ch != chList.end(); ++ch)
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<Affector*> > tempAff = ch->getemng()->getAffectorsInOrder();
    for (auto aff = tempAff.begin(); aff != tempAff.end(); ++aff)
    {
        affectors[aff->first].push_back(aff->second);
    }
    tempAff.clear();
    tempAff = ch->getpmng()->getAffectorsInOrder();
    for (auto aff = tempAff.begin(); aff != tempAff.end(); ++aff)
    {
        affectors[aff->first].push_back(aff->second);
    }
    ...
}
```

This will work, but feels inefficient. I can't use the insertion operation of the map since I need to preserve existing values in the vectors. Is there a better way to combine the maps I'm not thinking of?

Thanks

Comment: Is a multimap an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [Richard Corden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11698/richard-corden) I think that you really want to be using a `std::multimap`.

```
std::multimap<int, Affector*> affectors;
```

If you also make `tempAff` and `tempAff2` `std::multimap`s you can do:

```
affectors.insert(tempAff.begin(), tempAff.end());
affectors.insert(tempAff2.begin(), tempAff2.end());
```